# Share video to Facebook wall

Tags: c#, html, facebook, youtube, ooyala

Hi we are using third party tool 'ooyala' for our video in site,
Ooyala also provide similar functionality for sharing videos into Facebook via ooyala player, Similar to YouTube, we are using displaying all video on single(video) page, user can watch different video, but page is not post back.
Now problem is when we are going to share video to faceBook wall with this architecture, Ooyala player has predefined tags for sharing(similar other video player have for sharing video into Facebook wall). Tags are for examples:

```
<link rel='video_src' href='http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=BxZWw2NTruU9_ZvZffjOtKxWE19RtyQq&keepEmbedCode=true'/>     
<meta name='title' content="Wozniack&apos;s Big Deal" />
<meta name='description' content="Sports Business Analyst,Looks into Caroline Wozniacki&apos;s new sponorship deal." />
<link rel='image_src' href='http://ak.c.ooyala.com/BxZWw2NsTruU9_ZvZffjOtKxWE1df9RtyQq/4DSSlmQqiwve8yKn5hMDoxOjI0O1edhIv' />    
<title id="PageTitle">Video</title>    
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" name="viewport"/>     
<meta name="medium" content="video" />
```

**Problems is, these predefined tags in page header load once when page load, how we can change these tag without post back the page.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to have a individual page for each video. If you'd rather use Javascript to change the attributes everytime (which is not only tricky, but messy), I guess you can.

Comment: ya individual page for each video wil definitely work but we can't change our current player which is playing all video on single page without post back. whereas for mobile site,each video is playing on individual page and sharing video to Facebook is working prefect, but on desktop site, Video player is more important then sharing video on Facebook, so, not allowed for us to change Player for FB sharing. we only accommodate FB sharing with current player then it will be ok.